# how to use array with data from other file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have json file with categories and products. how can i use this data in the products file without load the file twice ?

i defined 2 routes files for products and categories. each category have list of products. i load the data in the category route file into array. how can i use this array in the product route ?

```
//json file example
 "categories": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "category1",
            "products" : [
                {
                    "categoryId":"",
                    "name" : "productName1",
                    "itemInStock" : 2
                },
                {
                    "categoryId":"",
                    "name" : "productName2",
                    "itemInStock" : 5
                }
             ]
        }

//loading file into array

const loadProductsCatsFile = () => {
  let jsonObj = fs.readFileSync('catsandprods.json');
  let catObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

  for (let key in catObj.categories) {
    if (catObj.categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      catObj.categories[key].id = uuid();
      for (let key2 in catObj.categories[key].products) {
        catObj.categories[key].products[key2].categoryId = catObj.categories[key].id;
        productsArr.push(catObj.categories[key].products[key2]);
      }
    }
  }
}

//products file
import { Category } from '../models/category';
```

Im trying to export the array from categories file and import it in the products file whitout success.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the `resolveJsonModule` compiler option (added in 2.9) in your tsconfig.json, then you will be able to import your json as if it were a regular Javascript/TypeScript module.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

```
import * as json from './place';
```

TypeScript will then correctly infer the types for this file.

Side note: if you have enabled `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` you can use the syntax:

```
import json from './place';
```

Alternatively, without any changes to tsconfig, you can use the `require` syntax, but the type for the required module will be `any`.

```
const json = require('./place');
```